# XPath expression for xml with a namespace prefix

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, biztalk, biztalk-2013

Given the following xml:

```
<ns0:MCCI_IN000002UV01 xmlns:ns0="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <ns0:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.277.100.1" extension="68423f2b-397a-4de4-8b8d-ea1f6c174954" />
    <ns0:creationTime>201410171106-0700</ns0:creationTime>
    <ns0:versionCode code="Ballot2009May" />
    <ns0:interactionId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.6" extension="MCCI_IN000002UV01" />
    <ns0:processingCode code="P" />
    <ns0:processingModeCode code="T" />
    <ns0:receiver nullFlavor="NA">
        <ns0:device nullFlavor="NA" classCode="DEV" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
            <ns0:id nullFlavor="NA" />
        </ns0:device>
    </ns0:receiver>
    <ns0:sender nullFlavor="NA">
        <ns0:device nullFlavor="NA" classCode="DEV" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
            <ns0:id nullFlavor="NA" />
        </ns0:device>
    </ns0:sender>
    <ns0:acknowledgement typeCode="CA">
        <ns0:targetMessage>
            <ns0:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.277.100.1" extension="adb32b05-bf62-4417-8c62-d37a65380c4f" />
        </ns0:targetMessage>
        <ns0:acknowledgementDetail typeCode="I" />
    </ns0:acknowledgement>
</ns0:MCCI_IN000002UV01>
```

I was unable to query the hl7:MCCI_IN000002UV01/hl7:versionCode/@code attribute using BizTalks XPathMutatorStream class unless I altered the xml and removed the namespace prefix.  So for example, the xml would now look like this:

```
<MCCI_IN000002UV01 xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.277.100.1" extension="68423f2b-397a-4de4-8b8d-ea1f6c174954" />
        ...
</MCCI_IN000002UV01>
```

Unfortunately I can't change the xml, so I have to deal with the ns0 prefix.

Basically, I create an XMLReader object by passing it a stream:

```
XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(strMyStream);
```

Then I create my XPathCollection with an XPathExpression:

```
XPathCollection xc = new XPathCollection();
xc.NamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xr.NameTable);
xc.NamespaceManager.AddNamespace("hl7", "urn:hl7-org:v3");
xc.Add(new XPathExpression("hl7:MCCI_IN000002UV01/hl7:versionCode/@code"));
```

The I pass my XPathCollection and XmlReader instances to a BizTalk XPathMutatorStream object:

```
XPathMutatorStream str = new XPathMutatorStream(xr, xc, ...);
```

This all works fine if there is no namespace prefix on the xml but as soon as there is, I never get any matches.  Is there something I need to do on the namespace manager, or in the actual xpath statements to get a match?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using the local-name() function?

For example: //*[local-name()='MCCI_IN000002UV01']/*[local-name()='versionCode']/@code

Comment: to make it robust, I suggest including the namespace-uri().I tried this
//*[local-name()='MCCI_IN000002UV01' and namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3' ]/*[local-name()='versionCode']/@code

Comment: Any reason why you would use "//*..." instead of "/*..."? I'm not sure, but I doubt the "//*" notation works with XPathMutatorStream. Checkout this article for more information and the pros & cons on XPathMutatorStream: http://www.codit.eu/blog/2010/01/22/the-biztalk-xpathmutatorstream-pros-and-cons/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Linq2Xml:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
```

**1-** Using XPath

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.CreateNavigator().NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("hl7", "urn:hl7-org:v3");

var version = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("hl7:MCCI_IN000002UV01/hl7:versionCode", mgr);
var code = version.Attribute("code").Value;
```

**2-** Using Linq

```
XNamespace h17 = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
var code2 = xDoc.Descendants(h17 + "versionCode").First().Attribute("code").Value;
```

Comment: I can get these all to work.  Ideally I wouldn't use any of these because they involve loading the entire XML into memory.  XPathMutatorStream doesn't require loading the entire set of data into an XDocument or XmlDocument so it is less memory intensive, which could be very important in a broker (BizTalk) scenario where messages could be large or concurrency could be high.